# What speech database and recording software should I use for a speech recognition application?

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech

I want to implement an application that would recognize our dialect.

1. I know that first, I need a speech database so I can make a speech corpus. What speech database would you recommend?
2. Will Audacity be fine for recording? If not, what do you recommend?

I already have a dictionary of words (35 words) and recording equipment.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the [MS Speech SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10121). It works for me. Unfortunately you did not mention what OS you are using and this is Windows only.

Comment: I see. I'm working in Windows 7 and Ubuntu because I'm still exploring speech recognition. If you don't mind, can you elaborate your answer? Because I want to train my application so it can recognize our dialect.

Answer (score 0):

> What speech database can you suggest?

Speech database is usually a text of files and a transcription file

> Will audacity be fine for recording? If not, what do you recommend?

Yes

> I already have the dictionary of words (35 words) and also an equipment for recording.

That should be enough

> If you have any time, I would like to ask for your contact to talk to you, an email perhaps
>   I would appreciate of any help.

You can try CMUSphinx toolkit for acoustic model training. See the corresponding tutorial section

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam

Sure, see

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/communicate